# React: Cross origin requests on loading file without local server

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, requirejs, reactjs

I have two modules - one in React JSX and another in JavaScript.

```
define(function (require) {
    var ExternalJSInterface = require("./../../utils/ExternalJSInterface");
    var ExternalJSXInterface = require("jsx!ExternalJSXInterface");
}
```

I'm getting this error while loading ExternalJSXInterface:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   file:///Users/.../../ExternalJSXInterface.jsx. Cross origin requests
>   are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome,
>   chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

I think same error should also come for ExternalJSInterface. But it's working fine loading this.

I'm using Chrome with flag setting `allow-file-access-from-files`.

Comment: Thai doesn't really seem to have anything to do with react but with the module loader you are using.

Comment: But when I run this on a local server, everything is working fine. Only when I tried to open it without a server, I get this error.

Comment: I'm just saying it has nothing to do with React. It could have something to do with JSX (which is independent of React), and it has definitely something to do with your module loader. And we still don't really know which one you are using.

Comment: Ok, now I get this.I'll try to resolve this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was indeed in the module loader as pointed out by Felix. My module loader was [jsx-requirejs-plugin](https://github.com/philix/jsx-requirejs-plugin) which was using [requirejs-text](https://github.com/requirejs/text) internally to load jsx files if we use require call.

As mentioned in the documentation of requirejs-text under configuration section, it suffers from XHR restriction which restrict it's usage if we use "file://" to access files.

The solution is present at this [link](http://www.bravenewgeek.com/using-make-with-react-and-requirejs/).

Hope it helps someone.